# D3 Force Network Layout with links and clustering

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to make a force network diagram with D3 that shows all of the connections between nodes, which I have successfully done. I also need to cluster the nodes to represent the different categories of the data. I cannot find a way to get both clustering and links to work together.

The jsfiddle here shows what I have so far: 
https://jsfiddle.net/joe642/3kL2w4Lr/1/

Here is an example of the data generated by the PHP source:

```
nodes = [{"name":1,"group":1},{"name":196,"group":2},{"name":232,"group":2},{"name":232,"group":1},{"name":232,"group":2},{"name":232,"group":1}],

        links = [{"source":0,"target":1},{"source":2,"target":3},{"source":1,"target":2},{"source":3,"target":4},{"source":4,"target":5},{"source":1,"target":5},{"source":3,"target":5},{"source":5,"target":2}]
```

Once the basic clustering is going, I would also like to add radiuses for the nodes, probably generated by PHP as well.

Basically I need it to look the same as it is now, but with each group of nodes pushed to the edges of the screen. The actual data is huge with about 500 nodes and 9000 links, generated PHP, so in the jsfiddle there is just some dummy data.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1804919)?

Comment: I have seen clustered force diagrams: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7882658, I've just never seen them with connections.

Comment: Ok, well maybe you need to arrange the links so it groups naturally.

Comment: The problem is these charts have gravity and charge, so no matter how I group them they will always reorganise themselves, unless I can find a way to force them away from each other.